# Explain isotopic uranium/perchloric acid digestion

Tags: experimental-chemistry

What is happening [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kODW0qHgThU)? Can you explain this technically as well as in layman's terms?

I'll summarize it. I see a technician moving fuming mixtures of presumably uranium and organic compounds on and off hot plates. Perchloric acid is mentioned, and a large bottle is present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is a perchlorate digestion, the technician needs more training.  The hood door must be lower despite the Official marker.  His cotton lab coat must NOT be exposed to vapors!  Sleeves should be *inside* long gloves.  He has a bottle of perchloric acid next to a running hot plate!  I'd have a 5-gallon bucket of water nearby if the gloves ignite.  As perchlorate digestions occasionally explode, and he's doing a lot of them, I'd wear goggles under the face shield and wear Dyneema or Spectra body armor under the lab coat.  One might have some concern for hands (longer pair of tongs) and neck, too.

He's apparently cooking off a sample of organics-contaminated uranium whatever for trace contamination or isotopic analysis.  Everything oxidizable will be gone, leaving uranium oxides.

That is NOT marked as a perchlorate fume hood!  Everything organic downwind of those fumes is a potential high explosive, and certainly a violently flammable material including its own oxidizer.  There will be massive corrosion of all metals.  You don't want to be standing, living, downwind of the exhaust stack.  OTOH, the operation is low cost/sample, and anybody off the street is a potential lab tech.